# Remove underscore from a string in R

Tags: r

In my data.frame, I have a column of type `character`, where all the values look like this : `123_456` (three digits, an underscore, three digits).

I need to transform these values to a `numeric`, and `as.numeric(my_dataframe$my_column)` gives me a `NA`. Therefore I need to remove the underscore first, in order to do `as.numeric`.

How would I do that please ?

Thanks

Comment: "_...and the codez-repz symbionts lived happily ever after_"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We can use `sub`

```
as.numeric(sub("_", "", my_dataframe$my_column))
```